# Можно ли в Pascal ABC заполнять сектора текстом?

Tags: pascalabc.net

Помогите пожалуйста сделать такую штуку как на фото, только с русским текстом. Секторы в паскале я могу нарисовать, но как заполнить их текстом? Возможно это можно сделать проще на других языках, просто с простыми модулями рисования я знаю только `Pascal`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```pascal
uses crt, GraphABC;
const A: array[1..33] of integer = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
var u, u0, S, i: integer;
begin
SetWindowSize(800, 800);
circle(400, 400, 50);
S:=0; 
u0:=0;
for i:=1 to 33 do
S:=S+A[i];
for i:=1 to 33 do
begin
SetBrushColor(rgb(255,255,255));
u:=u0+round(A[i]*360/S);
Pie(400,400,390,u0,u);
u0:=u; 
end;
drawcircle(400, 400, 330);
circle(400, 400, 270);
end.
```

Comment: Если у вас PascalABC.NET, то там, вроде, можно захостить WPF. А на WPF запросто можно текст по любому пути пустить, хоть по кругу. Пример можно посмотреть в журнале MSDN 2008 год, декабрь (нужно качать [chm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues)).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, PascalABC.NET, хмм, про WPF в нем не особо что-то видно, буду искать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выводить повернутый текст можно средствами самого PascalABC. Понравилась ваша задача, да и Pascal решил вспомнить. Изменил немного ваш код:

```
uses GraphABC;
const
  r1 = 180;
  r2 = 240;
  r3 = 300;
  r23 = (r2 + r3) div 2;
  w = 2 * r3;
  h = 2 * r3;
  cx = r3;
  cy = r3;
  N = 32;

procedure draw_rotated_text(x, y, a: integer; s: string);
var prev_a: real;
begin
  coordinate.OriginX := coordinate.OriginX + x;
  coordinate.OriginY := coordinate.OriginY + y;
  prev_a := coordinate.Angle;
  coordinate.Angle := a;
  DrawTextCentered(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
  coordinate.OriginX := coordinate.OriginX - x;
  coordinate.OriginY := coordinate.OriginY - y;
  coordinate.Angle := prev_a;
end;

var
  i, S, u0, u1, u01, x, y: integer;
  a, ai: real;

begin
  SetWindowSize(w, h);
  window.SetPos(300, 10);
  font.Size := 30;
  a := 0;
  ai := 360 / N;
  for i := 1 to N do
  begin
    u0 := round(a);
    u1 := round(a + ai);
    u01 := (u0 + u1) div 2;
    x := cx + round(r23 * cos(degtorad(u01)));
    y := cy - round(r23 * sin(degtorad(u01)));
    Pie(cx, cy, r3, u0, u1);
    draw_rotated_text(x, y, 90 - u01, 'A');
    a := a + ai;
  end;
  drawcircle(cx, cy, r2);
  circle(cx, cy, r1);
end.
```